# Developing Flash Application Using IntelliJ

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, intellij-idea

I know that IntelliJ makes it really easy for you to develop and start a FLEX project. However, I am wondering if there is a way to do the same with Flash App Development. I do not need the MXML file and other things that come with Flex. I just want to be able to start a Flash project like I would in Flash CS5 and be able to run the .swf file from IntellIJ. Not having the UI tools is not a concern to me.

Is there a way to do this. Are there ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any case you need Flex SDK, because IntelliJ IDEA takes compiler, debugger and libraries there. To use Flash classes (fl.*) you need to configure respective libraries in IDEA module dependencies. You'll find these SWCs in [Flash Pro installation]/Common/Configuration/Components